# Copying one file to another, while "expanding" some variables.

Tags: external-files, filesystem-access

The use case is that I have a template LaTeX file, which I would like to be copied several times while replacing variables in it to some other variables.

Here is an example of how such a template might look like:

```
   \documentclass[%POINT-SIZE%pt]{book}

    \includeonly{%CURRENT-CHAPTER%}
    \begin{document}
     \chapter{Chapter 1}
        \include{chapter1}
     \chapter{Chapter 2}
        \include{chapter1}

    \end{document}
```

The desired code should present read the file named "template.tex", and
copy it to four files named:

1. "10pt-chapter1-only.tex",
2. "12pt-chapter1-only.tex",
3. "10pt-chapter2-only.tex", *and*,
4. "12pt-chapter2-only.tex",

by replacing in template file:

- each occurrence of `%POINT-SIZE%` by the contents of the TeX macro `\pointSize`, *and*,
- each occurrence of `%CURRENT-CHAPTER%` by the contents of TeX macro `\currentChapterFileName`

Needless to say, there is nothing sacred in the way I chose to denote the variables in the template file.

Comment: unrelated but don't do `\chapter{Chapter 1}\include{chapter1}` put the `\chapter` in the included file (or you always get a page break after the heading)

Comment: why suggest `%` syntax and presumably some other macro expander rather than just use `\ ` and TeX macros, since expanding macros is what TeX is mainly written to do?

Comment: The template file looks like TeX code, but it is not TeX code. Most of the macros in it should not be expanded.Think of `\documentclass`. But, hey a solution of in the form of  a template with `\removeWhenCopyingButDoNotEpxand{` text spanning several paragraphs `}` may also work.

Answer (score 1):

I would let TeX do the macro expansion.

If your file is

```
   \documentclass[\pointSize]{book}
    \includeonly{\currentChapterFileName}
    \begin{document}
     \include{c1}
     \include{c2}
    \end{document}
```

then

```
 pdflatex '\def\pointSize{12pt}\def\currentChapterFileName{c1}\input' file
```

will make the 12pt version of chapter 1

Comment: Great idea! Except that I would not use the `pdflatex` command, but rather place the header you suggest in the copy file, and then copy the template right after it.

Comment: @YossiGil yes or you don't need to copy it you can just \input it

Comment: Yes, it is an option. In my context though, I would like to generate instance files which are as simple and self sustaining as possible.